# Can't find Magento 2 install on localhost

Tags: magento, installation, localhost

I ran my magento install with this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url='http://127.0.0.1/mage2'
 --db-host='localhost' --db-name=*** --db-user=*** 
--db-password=*** --admin-firstname='System' --admin-lastname='Administrator' 
--admin-email='admin@example.com' --admin-user=*** 
--admin-password=*** --language='sv_SE' --currency='SEK' 
--timezone='America/Chicago'
```

I expected my Magento 2 site to appear at http://www.my-magento-host.com/mage2 but it is empty.
The files are there if I go to root/(magento2-folder)/public_html. All the php bin/magento commands that I have tried works as well.
I just don't know where my site is...

---

My web browser displays this error:
Not Found
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at (my server ip) Port ****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct base url is not http://127.0.0.1/.
Its syntax looks like this http://111.111.111.111/.
So you need to enter the serverip or domain for the base-url.

For my case the correct base url was http://myserverip/mage2.